# Can the long guard block any type of punch?

Tags: muay-thai

So I heard that you can block punches with the long guard (especially overhands), so does that mean that you can block any type of punch with the long guard?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, no kind of guard helps against *every* type of punch. The long guard is particularly well-suited to limit the tactical options of an opponent, covering a lot of the possible punches. But [it has its limits](https://engageind.com/blogs/articles/how-to-fight-with-a-long-guard), especially as soon as people slip past it:

> When using the long guard, you must watch out for overhand rights, hooks, and low kicks.

On the other hand, as you *know* these limited options, you can watch out for them.

Comment: +1 for the "limiting of options". Defensive postures aren't just for defense, but also to reduce the number of options an attacker has, meaning fewer things to think about on the defensive side. (Not that they can be *ignored*, it's all about likelihoods.)